# Text align center wont work

Tags: html, css, alignment

On my website i have a position fixed footer, where i want to put centered text into. 
The strange thing is that, whatever im doing the text wont be centered, its always left instead.

```
<div id="footer">  
Copyright 2013 © LolStreamGallery - <a href="TermsofUse.html">Terms of Use</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    text-align:center;  
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#ededed;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Maybe you wann know the CSS of the Body also:

```
body {
    background-color:#ededed;
    /*text-align:left;*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0px; 
}
```

I have already tried to outcomment the body default align as you can see, but had no effect.
Anybody a idea?

Comment: This should tell you what is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/h6crw/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
#footer {
    text-align:center;  
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#ededed;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-size:14px;
    width:100%; // added
}
```

**[jsFiddle Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/w7qvg8d8/)**

Answer (score 2):

Your footer needs to stretch across the bottom.  Add a width:100% to your #footer style element.

```
#footer {
    text-align:center;  
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ededed;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-size:14px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4zqbX/

Answer (score 2):

When you set `#footer` to `position: fixed`, it doesn't have a width anymore. So technically, the content of `#footer` is still centered within `#footer`, but `#footer` takes it's width from the width of its content. So, you have to either get rid of `position: fixed` or give `#footer` a width. If you add `width: 100%` to `#footer` it should work.

Comment: I don't think your first statement is true @mrdanimal.  Maybe at some level, but not one that relates to the question.  Because this is a footer, it's position must be defined.  Simply adding a width of 100% which many have suggested is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need add a width to your #footer

```
#footer {
    text-align:center;  
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#ededed;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-size:14px;
    /*New*/
    width:100%;
}​
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/h6crw/1/

Answer (score 1):

It is because the text is in the center of the `div`, but if add a border, you then see the `div` is just as big as the text.

Just add a `width:100%;` to the footer and your done.